# How to add template suggestion for user--VIEW-MODE--ROLE.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, users

I used [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x):

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_user_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {

  // Define the view mode.
  $mode = $vars['elements']['#view_mode'];

  // Create a theme hook suggestion which has the view mode name in it.
  $suggestions[] = 'user__' . $mode;
}
```

Now I can work with `user--full.html.twig` and `user--compact.html.twig`

But I have a role `editor` and I want to `user--compact--editor.html.twig` to be picked up. How can I add a template suggestion based on user roles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is to get the current user object, get its roles, and then add the suggestion like in the following snippet. The current user also already is available in the `$variables`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_user_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  // Define the view mode.
  $view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');

  // Create a theme hook suggestion which has the view mode name in it.
  $suggestions[] = 'user__' . $view_mode;
    
  // Get current user.
  $current_user = $variables['elements']['#user'];

  // Get current user's roles.
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();

  // Add suggestion per role.
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $suggestions[] = 'user__' . $view_mode . '__' . $role;
  }
}
```

This will give you:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * user--full--administrator.html.twig
   * user--full--authenticated.html.twig
   * user--full.html.twig
   x user.html.twig
-->
```

Comment: Nice.  @leymannx would you be willing to be a maintainer of https://www.drupal.org/project/twigsuggest and add this?

Comment: @mlncn – Yes for the maintainership, as this really seems to be a useful module. About the snippets here, after I dropped that answer I thought to myself: What if a user has multiple roles, and there are multiple templates, how to decide which should be taken into account? Will it take just the first in alphabetical order? Worth some testing.

Comment: @lemannx excellent, done, thank you.  Oh, yeah, of course, on the multiple roles.  I was also thinking if there might be performance issues with getting roles... and now we're in the territory of building a UI for deciding if/which roles to do suggestions for...  maybe only if more need is demonstrated!

Comment: @mlncn – If roles in the UI are used as intended (with kind of an order from left "anonymous" to right "admin") we maybe only add one suggestion per user for its "highest" role?! Let's discuss this in the module's issue queue.

Comment: A little cleaner is to use the following (also check if they are available)

``` if ($current_user instanceof User) { ``` && ``` if (isset($variables['elements']['#view_mode'])) { ```